# Handling deleted id in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app with a social network component using Firebase, currently if a user likes a post I create a node in the user document called `likes` and I add the post id, example:

```
users: {
    k9EdVpyRJ2R2: {
        likes: {
            E36F50C: true
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if the post gets deleted should I just handle the deleted post-id on client side when I get the likes ids? or is there a better way to trim the data (or even restructuring it since the app is not live yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd typically remove the likes at the same time as you remove the post. To efficiently determine what likes to remove, you should keep a link from each post to its likes (in addition to the user-to-likes mapping you already have).

With that you can use a single multi-location update to remove the post and all likes. See this blog post for examples: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html